# Use grep to remove words from dictionary whose roots are already present

Tags: linux, bash, dictionary, grep

I am trying to write a random passphrase generator. I have a dictionary with a bunch of words and I would like to remove words whose root is already in the dictionary, so that a dictionary that looks like:

```
ablaze
able
abler
ablest
abloom
ably
```

would end up with only

```
ablaze
able
abloom
ably
```

because abler and ablest contain able which was previously used.

I would prefer to do this with grep so that I can learn more about how that works. I am capable of writing a program in c or python that will do this.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you get?. Right now, your question appears to be "write this program for me so I can learn from it" - please show some research effort.

Comment: @tucuxi Good point. I really wanted to see someone do it in grep as I'm capable of doing it in c or python. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: I think this is way more complicated that you think.  It's one thing to just blindly remove words that end in 'est', 'er', etc than it is to know that two words are related.  What do you do in case of words like goose vs geese?  Or what about two words that are similar but unrelated eg doner vs done?

Comment: @user1146334 I am content to leave geese and remove doner (although doner isn't in that dictionary, tone and toner has the same problem). I am not looking to compile a list of english word roots, just weed out suffixes that will make it harder to remember the correct passphrase (was it correct? corrected? corrects? horse? horses?).

Comment: @tucuxi The list I have is close to 20k words. It's taking a while to run, but isn't too terrible. I was really hoping for something more elegant that would teach me something about grep. If you want to write that solution in the answers, I'll mark it as the accepted answer in a few hours if something more efficient doesn't come along.

Comment: Assuming the list is sorted, you can simply iterate through the list, checking to see if the previous word is a prefix of the current word. However, this is not going to yield particularly good results for the English language (e.g. "see", "saw", "seen" all have the same root, but "saw" does not contain that root as a prefix, or "can", "cancer", "candy", which are completely unrelated). It may or may not be better in other languages...

Comment: Added a proof-of-concept answer. Although I would recommend Python (or almost anything else) over Bash for text processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the list is sorted so that shorter strings always precede longer strings, you might be able to get fairly good performance out of a simple Awk script.

```
awk '$1~r && p in k { next } { k[$1]++; print; r= "^" $1; p=$1 }' words
```

If the current word matches the prefix regex `r` (defined in a moment) and the prefix `p` (ditto) is in the list of seen keys, skip.  Otherwise, add the current word to the prefix keys, print the current line, create a regex which matches the current word at beginning of line (this is now the prefix regex `r`) and also remember the prefix string in `p`.

If all the similar strings are always adjacent (as they would be if you sort the file lexically), you could do away with `k` and `p` entirely too, I guess.

```
awk 'NR>1 && $1~r { next } { print; r="^" $1 }' words
```

Comment: While not `grep`-based, this solutions strikes me as the most elegant and probably best-performing.

Comment: Yes, this was by far the fastest solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is based on the assumption that the input file is sorted. In that case, when looking up each word, all matches after the first one can be safely skipped (because they will correspond to "the same word with a different suffix").

```
#/bin/bash
input=$1
while read -r word ; do
    # ignore short words
    if [ ${#word} -lt 4 ] ; then continue; fi
    # output this line
    echo $word 
    # skip next lines that start with $word as prefix
    skip=$(grep -c -E -e  "^${word}" $input)
    for ((i=1; i<$skip; i++)) ; do read -r word ; done
done <$input
```

Call as `./filter.sh input > output`

This takes somewhat less than 2 minutes on all words of 4 or more letters found in my `/usr/share/dict/american-english` dictionary. The algorithm is O(n²), and therefore unsuitable for large files.

However, you can speed things up a lot if you avoid using grep at all. This version takes only 4 seconds to do the job (because it does not need to scan the whole file almost once per word). Since it performs a single pass over the input, its complexity is O(n):

```
#/bin/bash
input=$1
while true ; do
    # use already-read word, or fail if cannot read new
    if [ -n "$next" ] ; then word=$next; unset next;
    elif ! read -r word ; then break; fi
    # ignore short words
    if [ ${#word} -lt 4 ] ; then continue; fi
    # output this word
    echo ${word}
    # skip words that start with $word as prefix
    while read -r next ; do
        unique=${next#$word}
        if [ ${#next} -eq ${#unique} ] ; then break; fi
    done
done <$input
```

Comment: That ran a lot faster than my attempt to iterate through the file. Even with 20k words, it took less than a minute.

Comment: < 2m on the full `american-english` file (restricted to 4-letter words, but orininally over 99k words). Using the `--mmap` flag does not make much of a difference. Disclaimer: I have an SSD.

Comment: My dictionary is the lower case american-english words with more than 4 letters[a-z] and no apostrophes.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you want to start with words that share the same first four (up to ten) letters, you could do something like this:

```
cp /usr/share/dict/words words
str="...."
for num in 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; do
    for word in `grep "^$str$" words`; do
        grep -v "^$word." words > words.tmp
        mv words.tmp words
    done
    str=".$str"
done
```

You wouldn't want to start with 1 letter, unless 'a' is not in your dictionary, etc.

Comment: Am I missing something? This script doesn't use $num anywhere.

Comment: It doesn't need the value of $num, since the length $str is being incremented each time. It is more to let the user know what is going on. It could have been written this way instead: `for str in .... ..... ...... ` (etc)

Answer (score 1):

Try this BASH script:

```
a=()
while read -r w; do
   [[ ${#a[@]} -eq 0 ]] && a+=("$w") && continue
   grep -qvf <(printf "^%s\n" "${a[@]}") <<< "$w" && a+=("$w")
done < file

printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}"
ablaze
able
abloom
ably
```

Comment: Nicely done. Suggestion: append `&& continue`  to the line with the first conditional (`... -eq 0 ...`), which allows you to drop the conditional (`... -gt 0 ...`) from the following line.

Comment: Glad to hear it - and thanks for the edit. You could now remove `[[ ${#a[@]} -gt 0 ]] && ` from the 2nd line in the loop body - after the edit, the condition is now by definition always met.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to weed out some of the words, this gross command will work.  Note that it'll throw out some legit words like best, but it's dead simple.  It assumes you have a test.txt file with one word per line

`egrep -v "er$|est$" test.txt >> results.txt`

egrep is the same as `grep -E`.  `-v` means throw out matching lines. `x|y` means if x **or** y match, and `$` means end of line, so you'd be looking for words that end in er or est

Comment: In fact "best" is a superlative so it might actually be a valid target, but this will also filter out "test" and "behest" and "father".  Probably too simplistic for any real use.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to group adverbs together. Some adverbs, including those that can also be adjectives, use er and est to form comparisons:

- able, abler, ablest
- fast, faster, fastest
- soon, sooner, soonest
- easy, easier, easiest

This procedure is know as *stemming* in natural language processing, and can be achieved using a stemmer or lemmatizer. there are popular implementations in python's NLTK module but the problem is not completely solved. The best out the box stemmer is the snowball stemmer but it does not stem adverbs to their root.

```
import nltk

initial = '''
ablaze
able
abler
ablest
abloom
ably
fast
faster
fastest
'''.splitlines()

snowball = nltk.stem.snowball.SnowballStemmer("english")
stemmed = [snowball.stem(word) for word in initial]

print set(stemmed)
```

output...

```
set(['', u'abli', u'faster', u'abl', u'fast', u'abler', u'abloom', u'ablest', u'fastest', u'ablaz'])
```

the other option is to use a regex stemmer but this has its own difficulties I'm afraid.

```
patterns = "er$|est$"
regex_stemmer = nltk.stem.RegexpStemmer(patterns, 4)
stemmed = [regex_stemmer.stem(word) for word in initial]

print set(stemmed)
```

output...

```
set(['', 'abloom', 'able', 'abl', 'fast', 'ably', 'ablaze'])
```

Comment: I mentioned in the comments on the original question that I'm not trying to compile a list of root words, just eliminated stuff that might make a combination of random words harder to remember (and also that I could do this problem in python, but was looking for a straight grep solution). Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: My bad, first attempt at a stack overflow answer and I didn't even read the question :0 . lesson learned.