# Linux: remove strings from list if they have substrings elsewhere in list

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, substring

I would like to take a list of strings and keep only those that have no substrings elsewhere in the list. To illustrate, I have this list:

```
apple
applesauce
kiwi
mango
mangoes
mangosteen
oranges
pineapples
```

I want to reduce it down to a list of strings which do not have any substrings elsewhere in the list. So, the resulting list would be:

```
apple
kiwi
mango
oranges
```

Note that `applesauce` and `pineapples` were removed because `apple` is elsewhere in the list and is a substring of both those words.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238090/use-grep-to-remove-words-from-dictionary-whose-roots-are-already-present) but it seems to be aimed specifically at prefixes, e.g. `ablaze, able, abler, ablest`. Based on that method, I tried the following with a pre-sorted copy of my list and it just printed the entire list, without even removing `applesauce` which I thought it would:

```
awk '$1~r && p in k { next } { k[$1]++; print; r= "^" $1; p=$1 }' fruitsorted.txt
```

Even if it had worked as I expected, it would still miss `pineapple` in my list.

Note that in an extreme case, if the list contained all the letters of the alphabet (or ASCII char set I guess) each on a separate line, then regardless of what else was in the list, the ouput would just be the alphabet/ char set.

Also, my starting list is unsorted. I don't really care if the resulting list is sorted although that's obviously trivial with `sort`.

Ideally I would like a somewhat compact shell command/ sequence of stuff like grep/ sort/ awk, as opposed to a longer form Perl/ Python/ whatever script which I already know how to implement.

Thanks.

**Update**

As pointed out by Ed Morton below, even sorting the list may mess up some basic approaches, e.g. in the following example, approaches that are assuming a sorted list will probably fail to remove `berryplum` since its substring `plum` comes after it. The second approach shown by 123 handles this case.

```
apple
applesauce
berryplum
kiwi
mango
mangoes
mangosteen
oranges
pineapples
plum
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list is sorted it's pretty simple

```
awk '{for(i in a)if(index($0,i))next;a[$0]}1' file

apple
kiwi
mango
oranges
```

Basically just loops over an array for each line, and checks if elements exist in the line. Adds to array if this is not the case.

For unsorted list this should work

```
awk '{for(i in a){if(index(i,$0)&&$0!=i)delete a[i];if(index($0,i))next}a[$0];next}
     END{for(i in a)print i}' file
```

Tested on [Wordlist](https://pastebin.com/raw/mRxN2eeB) for performance.

```
real    0m29.932s
user    0m29.918s
sys     0m0.008s
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and it did not work. Tried it as follows: `awk '{for(i in a)if(index($0,i))next;a[$0]}1' fruitsorted.txt`, where `fruitsorted.txt` is the list I showed at the top of my question. This just reprints the entire list with nothing removed. Note I'm using Cygwin Bash (minntty 2.7.7). Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: @SSilk Does the file contain carriage returns?

Comment: @123 Yes, each line appears to end with a carriage return and linefeed (`CR` and `LF` when syntax Show All Characters turned on in Notepad++).

Comment: @EdMorton Good point with the appleplum example. I'll update my question to include a similar example. Note that the second method shown by 123 works for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
   NR==FNR { fruits[$0]; next }
   {
       for (fruit in fruits) {
           if ((fruit != $0) && index($0,fruit)) {
               next
           }
        }
        final[$0]
    }
    END {
        for (fruit in final) {
            print fruit
        }
    }
' file file
mango
apple
oranges
kiwi
```

You can cram it all onto one line if you find that valuable:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{fruits[$0];next} {for (fruit in fruits) if ((fruit != $0) && index($0,fruit)) next; final[$0]} END{for (fruit in final) print fruit}' file file
```

Comment: Does this approach cover any special cases not covered by the second example shown by 123 below? His appears a bit more compact, though maybe he's just using shorter variable names.

Comment: @SSilk As far as I can tell they both cover the same cases. The only difference is that every line is read into an array and reads the file twice to update, whereas in mine the lines are added to the array on a line by line basis and the file is read once.Other than that they are basically the same. Both answers are going to produce the same results anyway though.

Comment: Right, it's just shorter variable names and no white space. If you remove all the cosmetic white space from mine and change all variable names to single chars it's slightly briefer than 123s. I **know** my solution covers all possible cases, idk if there's any that 123s misses since it's building up the equivalent of my `fruits` array on the fly so **maybe** there's some situation where something it should have checked was earlier in the file and so already skipped - i really don't know, think it through and consider all cases (lifes too short for me to do it!).

Answer (score 0):

For an unsorted list this may help :

```
awk 'NR==FNR{f1[NR]=$0;f2[$0]}
    END{
    for(i=0;i<=NR;i++){
      for(j in f2){
        if(match(f1[i],j)>=1){
            if(length(j)<length(f1[i])){
            f1[i]="nullfruit"
            }
        }
      }
    }
    for(i=0;i<=NR;i++){
         if(f1[i]!="nullfruit"){
            print f1[i];
            }
    }
    }' filename

apple
kiwi
mango
oranges
```

---

<sup>**Note:** pretty sure more *subtle* solutions exists.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ cat f1
apple
applesauce
berryplum
kiwi
mango
mangoes
mangosteen
oranges
pineapples
plum
```

You can use a little more looping to avoid reading the file twice or being concerned about order:

```
$ awk '{words[$1]}
     END{
        for (e in words)
            for (f in words)
                if (f!=e && index(e,f)) 
                    not[e]   
        for (e in words)
           if (!(e in not))
               print e}' f1
mango
plum
apple
oranges
kiwi
```